# confused with multiple AND predicates

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE classi_type = '3'
  AND job_role IN (52)
  AND job_qualification IN (25)
  AND job_type IN (7)
  AND job_gender = 'Female'
  AND (job_expmin >= '5'
       AND job_expmax <= '10')
  OR (job_salmin >= '0'
      AND job_salmax <= '30000')
  OR (job_agemin >= '24'
      AND job_agemax <= '33')
```

The `IN` conditions are working. Problem is with multiple `AND`.

Comment: It is almost always a good idea to force order of evaluation when mixing OR and AND; even if you're sure the default precedence works in your favor, it makes your intent clear.

Comment: And do you expect we guess what was you expecting to get as right result? BTW: `in` condition with just one value, makes no sense. You can replace `>= <=` conditions by `BETWEEN value1 AND value2` for a better understanding.

Comment: You need to provide your desired logic...

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need the right parentheses:

```
Select *
from table 
where classi_type = '3' AND
      job_role IN (52) AND
      job_qualification IN (25) AND
      job_type IN (7) AND
      job_gender = 'Female' AND
      ((job_expmin >= 5 AND job_expmax <= 10) OR
       (job_salmin >= 0 AND job_salmax <= 30000) OR
       (job_agemin >= 24 AND job_agemax <= 33)
     )
```

I am guessing that the last six referenced columns are really numbers of some sort.  The comparisons should be to numbers, not strings.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE classi_type = '3'
  AND job_role IN (52)
  AND job_qualification IN (25)
  AND job_type IN (7)
  AND job_gender = 'Female'
  AND job_expmin >= '5'
  AND job_expmax <= '10'
  AND job_salmin >= '0'
  AND job_salmax <= '30000'
  AND job_agemin >= '24'
  AND job_agemax <= '33'
```